# hola buenas, como lo puedo hacer para que los datos obtenidos en la consulta los pueda pasar a unos input a mi index.ejs, ¿se puede hacer eso?

Tags: javascript, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los datos obtenidos en el results(los cuales me entrega un RowDataPackt) los quiero pasar a input
de type="text" y he buscado info pero no encuentro nada me podrian guiar si es se puede hacer o su alguna otra manera se agradeceria

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: [es.so] no es un sitio de tutoriales. Además, el código va siempre _como texto, con formato_. Pulsa en [edit] y adapta tu pregunta a un problema _específico_. Lee lo que te han indicado anteriormente, y [ask]. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: *¿se puede hacer eso?* Sí. Se puede.